# paypal - how to make multivendor ecommerce

Tags: node.js, paypal

I'm trying to develop multivendor e-commerce by node.js but when i learned paypal integration with node.js, i learned that i can send the money to one vendor because i can type one client id and one secret id like this

```
paypal.configure({
  'mode': 'sandbox', //sandbox or live
  'client_id': 'EBWKjlELKMYqRNQ6sYvFo64FtaRLRR5BdHEESmha49TM',
  'client_secret': 'EO422dn3gQLgDbuwqTjzrFgFtaRLRR5BdHEESmha49TM'
});
```

so how can i send the money to more than one vendor!

Answer (score 0):

Use `payee` in the Order creation request to specify a different account as the receiver of the payment. See [the documentation.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/customize/pay-another-account/)

```js
{
  intent: 'CAPTURE',
  purchase_units: [{
    amount: {
      currency_code: 'USD',
      value: '220.00'
    },
    payee: {
      email_address: 'receiveraccount@emaildomain.com'
    }
  }]
}
```

Comment: But what if i have a cart and this cart has a lot of products and each product has a different vendor and then i want to buy this cart ... How the money of each vendor go to the right vendor

Comment: There is something called multiseller payments https://developer.paypal.com/docs/multiparty/checkout/multiseller-payments/ , I don't know if it works without being a PayPal partner though